# Count blank cells above a cell stopping at the next non blank cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there an excel formula to count the blank cells in a column ABOVE the 1 and stopping at the next non blank>?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula - starting at row 2.
Using it in row 1 it will throw an error:

```vb
=IF(A2=1,
LET(data,$A$1:A1,
rowPrevious1,MAX(FILTER(ROW(data),data=1,0)),
ROWS(FILTER(data,(ROW(data)>rowPrevious1)*(data=""),0))),"")
```

`data` starts at A1 and runs until the row before the formula - you will see this when pulling down the formula.

`rowPrevious1` then  returns the max row of previous 1

The last step filters all cells (within data) whose row is > rowPrevious1 and that are empty. `ROWS` counts the returned number of empty cells.

[image]

Comment: LET is certainty useful! Thanks again